# Non-cyclic Field Automorphism Group

Tags: field-theory, automorphism-group

I failed to find an example of a field F with non-cyclic Group Aut(F).

Must Aut(F) be a Cyclic Group for any field F?

Comment: Does $\mathbb R$ have a cyclic group of automorphisms?

Comment: @Alessandro Yes, $Aut(\Bbb R)$ is trivial, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map). The trivial group is cyclic. But what about [$Aut(\Bbb C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527893/how-many-automorphisms-mathbbc-has)?

Comment: The simplest example is probably $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,i)$. Then you might want to look at $Aut(\Bbb{C}(t)/\Bbb{C})=PGL_2(\Bbb{C})$.